# Hidden id on tkInter Listbox

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow store a hidden id along with each entry on a Listbox. The reason for this is that I've got a table which contains a unique id which is from a database (not visible to the user but used to uniquely identify each record) I'm caching the table in memory and using a dictionary keyed on the id

I'd like to create a Listbox which allows me to select one of the records - the displayed text would not be the unique id but a descriptive field (such as 'Name') which is probably unique but this is not enforced and there is no index on it. So for example, If I have:

```
Id  Name
--  ----
 2  Rod
 5  Jane
15  Freddy
```

Then selecting `Jane`, I would somehow be able to easily access the id `5`

My problem is that I can't find a way to associate the unique id (`5`) with the selection (`Jane`) so that I can easily identify the cached record. I know that I can use control variables but this just gives me a list of all the strings in the list - not what I want. Also, the index (for example on insert) does not seem to be reliable for this purpose.

The only way that I've managed to do this is to have another dictionary mapping the name to the id. For a number of reasons, this is sub-optimal.

Am I missing something here? Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: You mean id `5` for `Jane`, and `2` for `Rod`, right? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, apologies. Corrected that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your ids in a list, then use the `.curselection()` index to map these back to the row ids, as long as you keep the ordering the same.

In your example, `Jane` is the second choice in your list, so if selected `.curselection()` returns `1`. If you have a `rowids` list in the same order, `rowids[1]` will be `5`:

```
>>> rowids = [2, 5, 15]
>>> rowids[listbox.curselection()]
5
```

Slightly more efficient than mapping names to rowids in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. An added complexity that I didn't mention is that I might have to handle deletions / insertions. It's looking to me more and more that I need to have a fair amount of boilerplate code to manage the relationship between the 'model' and the 'view'. For example, there doesn't appear to be any facility to sort on insert - easy enough to do, but a common enough requirement, you'd think, to merit adding the functionality into the container. Maybe I'm justt expecting too much.

Comment: Yes, for a ListBox you'd need to then include a decent model class to keep things sorted and keep track of the relationship between indices and your row ids.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [ttk.Treeview](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) widget instead of a Listbox, you can store the id in an invisible column.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Python 2.6.2 which doesn't seem to have support for Treeview - which is a great shame, and I've no control over the version.