# What's the best solution for inserting into normalized tables in Microsoft Access using PYODBC?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

For example if I have an example table:

Customers

---

```
ID | Name  | StateID | RepID

1  | Cust1 |    1    |  1

2  | Cust2 |    2    |  5
```

Here are some options I came up with:

1. Write a query for each foreign key I have. For example, my GUI I have a user wanting to enter a customer with values: Cust3, New Jersey, Mike Smith. Then for New Jersey, I would query my database to find the ID associated wit New Jersey and Mike Smith. Then I would use those IDs to insert the final data into my customers table. If my table had many columns this could be a lot of querying.
2. Most of the data the users are entering are from drop-downs. The data from these drop-downs are coming from my database, and most of the time I am just querying the specific piece of data (like state for example). Instead, I could query the database with both the state/ID and load it into an object so that I already have all keys associated with the fields.
3. Is there any possibility of running VBA code from a PYODBC connection?
4. Give up and look into getting a SQL server instance on AWS.

How can i insert data in Microsoft Access using PYODBC?

Comment: Try setting up in GUI drop down hidden values of corresponding ID but display the human-readable, lookup value. Web forms to Access forms have this capability, even Python's `tkinter`.

Comment: Hmmm, I need to look into that more, but it sounds just what I'm looking for. I'm using tkinter so hopefully either doing it in Access/Tkinter will lead me to my goal. Thanks again for the help Parfait.

Comment: See: [Hidden id on tkInter Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10751735/1422451)